# Was there ever a film, comic, or toon where Batman had Spider-Man's (or Spider-Man-like) powers?

Tags: story-identification, batman, spider-man, fan-fiction

A friend of mine **swears** this exists, and has for years, in which case I thought:

1. It would have to be a **fan made story** of sorts, such as *doujinshi* or fan made video. No such officially sanctioned comic or story---- at least, not far as I have been able to research---- exists, even within the *Amalgam* universe. The same friend showed me some fan art online some years back, but there was a lot of it, from a few different sources, and there is fan art for almost *every possible thing,* now. None of that, however, counts as an actual published or broadcast story.

Or the other possibility...

2. There **was** some little-known hero of a totally different name, who had a *similar aesthetic*  to a combination of Batman/Spider-Man, and he [my buddy] got this mixed up with the originals. This *can* happen; at one point I originally thought Shadow Hawk was a new version of Wolverine due to their similar looks.It was the 90s/2000s, and a certain type of ""extreme look" was pretty popular in comics at the time..

[image]

Adding to this is the fact that Stan "The Man" Lee *himself* **did!** actually do a re-imagining of some DC icons, including Batman. This Batman had *no* Spider-Man powers, or powers of any kind, though....

[image]

I've never known my buddy, a comic geek in his own right, to make such mistakes, though. So I'm wondering if anyone knows if:

(a) an actual story where Batman got spider-like powers exists?

or

(b) if there was some short lived, small time, unofficial or fan made comic/film where such a character was shown?

Comment: *SpiderBat aka Bruce Parker*?

Comment: @Shreedhar is this _really_ a THING?????

Comment: yeah. Check my answer.

Answer (score 10):

As far as I can tell, using the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_versions_of_Batman#Canon_depictions) as a source, there was no "Spider-Bat" or "Bat-Spider" as an actual character.

The only official version that I can find that *might* match this version of "Batman with Spider-Man's abilities" is a one-off crossover called [Disordered Minds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_and_Batman:_Disordered_Minds). In this one-shot, Batman and Spider-Man work together to stop Carnage and The Joker; in the course of this, Batman is enveloped by the Carnage Symbiote:

> The Joker tries to kill Carnage with a bomb, but Carnage drapes a piece of symbiote over a corpse to fake his death. Batman and Spider-Man uncover the trick, and Batman is subsequently engulfed in Carnage's symbiote tendrils.

As we know about Carnage, he has the [abilities of Spider-Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnage_(comics)#Powers_and_abilities); derived from Venom, whom adopted the abilities from his original host, Spider-Man (emphasis mine):

> The alien symbiote endows Kasady with physical strength greater than that of Spider-Man and Venom combined and shape-shifting abilities, **allows him to project a web-like substance** from any part of his body including the formation of weapons, and enables him to plant thoughts into a person's head using a symbiote tendril. Much like Spider-Man, Kasady has the **ability to cling to virtually any surface, and has a version of Spider-Man's spider-sense**, as the symbiote can relay information to him from any angle and grants Kasady the ability to "see" in any direction, warning him of incoming threats.

While this might be the character your friend is thinking of, I cannot specify whether or not the Carnage Symbiote actually grants Batman these abilities, or simply attempts to control him, as Batman fights to regain control over himself, and fight off the Symbiote, while Spider-Man deals with the Joker.

---

As a sidenote, there was an official cross-over between the DC and Marvel Universe, and one character was Logan Wayne a.k.a Dark Claw, which was the amalgamation of Batman and Wolverine; and Peter Ross a.k.a Spiderboy, the amalgamation of Superboy and (a clone of) Spider-Man

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Amalgam_Comics_characters#DC_versus_Marvel/Marvel_versus_DC_#1-4)

Comment: In the scene you're describing, the majority of the Carnage symbiote remained with Cletus Kasady. Batman was just constrained by a few tendrils, which wrapped around his arms and torso. He wasn't fully enveloped by the symbiote, and didn't gain any powers. In fact, he was helpless in that scene, and completely at Carnage's mercy. Ironically, he was saved by the Joker, who didn't like the idea of anyone else killing Batman, and managed to frighten Kasady into losing control of his symbiote by threatening to unleash a deadly airborne pathogen.

Answer (score 6):

The amalgamation is indeed a fan-fiction character called, (*drums rolls*), **SPIDERBAT**. The story was posted over 9 years ago so, this could be what your friend saw.

Written by a [Comicvine Gamespot forum](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/) user with the handle **[GR2Blackout](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/profile/gr2blackout/)**, the Spiderbat is confirmed to be a fanfic:

> *This is an independent fanfic about a Spider-Man/Batman combo I came up with*.

It is a two-part story:

> **Part 1**: *[Night of the Man Lizard](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/forums/fan-fic-8/spiderbat-1-669548/)*
>
> **Part 2**: *[The Flight of The Fowl](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/forums/fan-fic-8/spiderbat-2-671006/)*

The origins story of the Spiderbat is narrated by Bruce Parker in the second part as:

> *A long time ago, I, Bruce Parker, witnessed my parents die before my own eyes. Thomas and Martha Parker owned Parker Industries, a huge science company. I, Bruce, inherited the company. But one day, during a science expo, my hand was bitten by a special genetic project we were doing on a rare type of spider. The bite filled my DNA and blood with a toxic venom. I gained special abilities, like amazing agility, hand to hand combat, and, the most spectacular of all... wall-crawling. I used the abilities to avenge my parents death, and took my name from the rare spider that bit me... I am SPIDERBAT!*

Answer (score 4):

Spider-Boy is a combination of Spider-Man and Super-Boy, and his powers are gravity related, but he kind of sort of looks a little Bat-Man-like, in a way, I guess.

https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Ross_(Amalgam_Universe)

Comment: Thanks, I know the Spiderboy comic. It's from the _Amalgam_ universe from 1996. Told him about it, and as there is no Batman aspect, this isn't what he was looking for.